# Mirror column plot with different y-axis in ggplot

Tags: r, visualization, ggplot2

I am trying to convert this plot
[image]

Into a mirror column plot
[image]

I have two datasets:

1. school_purchases
2. recent_school_shootings

I am not very experienced with visualisation but this is my approach

```
ggplot(school_purchases_month, aes(x = date, y = total)) +
  geom_col(fill = "black", color = "white") #this plots one column chart of spending
```

I also want **recent_school_shootings$killed** on the other side

```
recent_school_shootings$killed=mutate(recent_school_shootings, killed= -killed)

ggplot(school_purchases_month, aes(x = date, y = total)) +
  geom_col(fill = "black", color = "white") +
  geom_col(data = subset(recent_school_shootings, killed > 0), 
             aes(x = date, y = killed))
```

but it's throwing all kinds of error. Can you point me in right direction?

Comment: You should provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Would you follow the instructions in the link above, and provide an example with sample dataset? Using `dput(head(dataset))` on each of your dataframes probably works.

Comment: *"but it's throwing all kinds of error"* ... If you share the actual errors, that'd be helpful too.

Comment: The problem could be lying on this line: ```recent_school_shootings$killed=mutate(recent_school_shootings, killed= -killed)``` change it to ```recent_school_shootings=mutate(recent_school_shootings, killed= -killed)```

Answer (score 3):

You can either reshape the data into long format (after joining the two datasets) and use `geom_col` once, or have two geoms as you have in your question. However, the latter needs some variation to have the `aes` in `geom_col` and not in `ggplot`.

Below, I have an example with `mpg` dataset, illustrating the two options (except the joining). I also included an example with your datasets but since you don't have a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), I cannot be sure of the outcome.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
```

```r
## Calling geom_col twice
mpg %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% 
  select(manufacturer, cty, hwy) %>% 
 ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=manufacturer, y=hwy, fill="hwy")) +
  geom_col(aes(x=manufacturer, y=-cty, fill="cty")) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.4))

## Converting data to long format
mpg %>% 
  group_by(manufacturer) %>% 
  summarise_if(is.numeric, mean) %>% 
  mutate(cty = -cty) %>% 
  select(manufacturer, cty, hwy) %>% 
  pivot_longer(., -manufacturer) %>% 
 ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=manufacturer, y=value, fill=name)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.4))
```

[image]

For your datasets, first we join them on `date` column and then we can use `geom_col` on each of the desired columns. Note that I have `aes` in `geom_col` and not in the `ggplot`. You need to make sure that your `date` column is not class of `factor` (but joining may resolve that issue). If you shared output of `dput(head(dataset))` for each of your two datasets, I could further investigate your problem.

```r
recent_school_shootings %>% 
  full_join(., school_purchases_month, by = "date", suffix = c("s", "p")) %>%
 ggplot() +
  geom_col(aes(x=date, y=total, fill="Purchase")) +
  geom_col(aes(x=date, y=-killed, fill="Shooting"))
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>